# Ember view dropdown Dropdown has empty labels

Tags: ember.js

When I use this model the Dropdown has empty labels. I set the label path to type. My server returns 2 models in json and I see 2 dropdown items (empty)

```
export default DS.Model.extend({ 
    type: DS.attr('string') 
    }); 


    {{view "select" prompt="Account type" content=model optionLabelPath="type" optionValuePath="id"}}
```

Comment: you dont have id property returned from model and you are giving optionsValuePath as 'id'

Comment: @Vaibhav you dont need that for the model.

Comment: the server returns the id

Comment: OK, can you put a debugger in template and check what data exactly coming.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

{{view "select" prompt="Account type" content=model optionLabelPath="content.type" optionValuePath="content.id"}}